# Data is not adding to Plist

Tags: ios, xcode, nsarray, plist, nsdictionary

Hi i created one plist in xcode (`newfile->resourses->property list`  like this) and i try to add one `NSDictionary` to that plist but its not adding ,please help me here is my code

```
    -(IBAction)Add:(id)sender {
     _pdfbookmark = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[[NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"pdfBookmarksdata" ofType:@"plist"]] objectForKey:_bookID]];

     NSMutableDictionary *bookmark = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"pdfBookmarksdata" ofType:@"plist"]];

     if(self.bookmarkIndicator.tintColor == [UIColor blueColor]){
        //Already Bookmarked
        [_pdfbookmark removeObjectAtIndex:currentBookmarkIndex];
        self.bookmarkIndicator.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
     }else{
        //Create Bookmark
        [_pdfbookmark addObject:
        @{@"deviceid": @"0",
        @"page" : [NSNumber numberWithInt:[self getGlobalPageCount]],
        @"fontsize" : [NSNumber numberWithInt:currentTextSize]}];
        self.bookmarkIndicator.tintColor = [UIColor blueColor];
   }
    [bookmark setObject:_pdfbookmark forKey:_bookID];
    [bookmark writeToFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"pdfBookmarksdata" ofType:@"plist"] atomically:YES];
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not allowed to write files to your main bundle.  If you check the return of the `writeToFile:` method, you will see that it returns `NO`.

Comment: so how can i write to plist?

Comment: Copy it somewhere else.  There are a bazillion places that will show you how to do this on google.  Read this as well -> http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGUide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html